# Is it possible to set a specific alignment for each part of the text within a Term.jl's Panel?

Tags: julia

I want to apply a specific alignment for each part of a text within a Panel. Expected output:

```
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│  left                                          │
│                    center                      │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Then I tried:

```
julia> using Term: Panel

julia> println(
           Panel(
               "{bold left}left{/bold /left}\n{center}center{/center}",
               width=50
           )
       )
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│  {bold left}left{/bold /left}                  │
│  center                                        │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

But it aligns them all to the left.
I want to know even if this is possible to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this hint](https://github.com/FedeClaudi/Term.jl/issues/163#issuecomment-1323762355) from the maintainer, I should do this:

```
julia> left = RenderableText("left"; width=45, justify=:left);
       center = RenderableText("center"; width=45, justify=:center);

julia> println(
           Panel(
               left,
               center,
               width=50
           )
       )
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│  left                                          │
│                                                │
│                     center                     │
│                                                │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```